# Insert directly multi data rows with multi column to DynamoDB using API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, bulkinsert

I'm trying to insert data to DynamoDB directly with API Gateway. I can insert single, but get stuck with insert **multiple** data rows. May be problem with the mapping template (always get *com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException* error)

1. My dynamoDB table structure `ex_table`: time, column1, column2
2. My gateway mapping template:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.json('$.items')})
{
    "TableName": "ex_table",
    "Item":
    [
        #foreach($elem in $inputRoot) {
            "time": {"S": $input.json('$.time')},
            "column1": "$elem.column1.S",
            "column2": "$elem.column2.S",
        }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
        #end
    ]
}
```

3. And this is my request body:

```
{
  "time": "2021-03-31 16:50:00",
  "items": [
    {
      "column1": "Item1",
      "column2": "Attr1"
    },
    {
      "column1": "Item2",
      "column2": "Attr2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can you guys help me this. Many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is "BatchWriteItem" in the [DynamoDB API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html#API_BatchWriteItem_Examples).  Instead of the normal Item{...} syntax for single writes, BatchWriteItem takes a slightly diff style:

```
{"RequestItems":{
    "TableName": [
        {"PutRequest" : {
            "Item": {
                "Name":{"S" : "Some Name"},
                "Category":{"S" : "Some Category"}
            }
        }},
        {"PutRequest" : {
            "Item": {
                "Name":{"S" : "Some Name 2"},
                "Category":{"S" : "Some Category 2"}
            }
        }}
    ]
}}
```

Combined with changing the action within APIGateway to BatchWriteItem and updating your mapping template like this (untested) should get you there (or close):

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.json('$.items')})
{
    "RequestItems": {
        "ex_table" : [
            #foreach($elem in $inputRoot) {
                "PutRequest" : {
                    "Item" : {
                        "time": {"S": $input.json('$.time')},
                        "column1": "$elem.column1.S",
                        "column2": "$elem.column2.S",
                    }
                }
            }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
            #end
        ]
    }
}
```